# Qt changing an item within a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, char, hex

I am struggling with changing the 4th byte in a char array with hexes inside. I need to change the 4th byte (0x00) in the char str[5].

Is there any built in library or a command which I can use for my code?

```
 QString setVal = QString::number( ui->gainSpinBox->value(), 16 ).toUpper();
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(setVal, 3000);

    char str [5] = {0xE6, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0xe6};
```

Comment: *"I am struggling with changing the 4th byte"*, *"I need to change the 3rd byte"*, anyways, where are you *trying* to actually modify it? What does Qt have to do with this?

Comment: It is the 4th one. I wrote it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a `char` array has `char`s inside, not "hexes". The latter is your *formatting* choice.

`str[3] = '\0'` sets the fourth element of `str` to 0, but **since it's zero anyway**, this is a no-op.

`'\0'` is a `char` type, which is why I've written it this way.